# Rails send mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I am trying to send an email on an existing view that was created prior to needing a mailer. I am using legacy code and have already set up my mailer and controller. I have something like this:

```
<% link_to 'blah',
   { :controller => '/some_controller',
     :action => 'deliver_email',
     :purchase_id => 'blah.to_id
   }
```

It sends the email according to my logs but I'm getting a message that I need to create a view.

I don't want to create another view just send on the existing page(a different view) where this code is needed, but without using the GET request. It has to be POST.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect within your deliver_email action after the email was sent.

```
def deliver_email
  YourMailer.mailer_action(@user).deliver_now
  redirect_to your_redirect_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a :remote option in link_to helper. It makes your link_to as ajax, so you can response to javascript without redirect. check [working with javascript in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) from rails guides. I didn't test, but code may looks like below.

view:

```
<% link_to 'blah', controller: '/some_controller', action:  'deliver_email', purchase_id: blah.to_id, remote: true %>
```

controller:

```
# app/controllers/some_controller.rb
def deliver_email
  YourMailer.mailer_action(@user).deliver_now
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

js:

```
# app/views/some/deliver_email.js.erb
alert("Success");
```